# How to select an asp.net control using ID in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a webform with some asp.net controls and I would like to select each control using their ID. When I launch the page all the names get changed.

Is there an easy way to use this. I would prefer not use class as a selector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using asp.net 4 you can set the ClientIDMode tag to Static. That will prevent asp.net from changing the ID of the controls.

```
    <asp:Button ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Comment: That's too simple. Thanks

Comment: @KathyJudd You can set this at the `web.config` level so that you don't have to add `ClientIdMode="Static"` for every control you want to reference. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/950xf363(v=vs.100).aspx). You can also set it at the page level.

Answer (score 3):

After Rendering controls id will chaged something like `cph_master_labelid`

using `jquery`

```
var id=$(#'<%labelid.ClientID %>')
```

or You can Set its server side Property `[Control.ClientIDMode][1]"` Used only in 4.0 or greater

```
<asp:Label id="mylabel" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```